# PHP Currency Converter Not Working

Tags: php

To any Advanced PHP users out there I am a Begginer. So, I have this PHP currency converter that I am currently working on:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Currency Converter</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Currency Converter</h1>
        <form action="index.php" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="input" placeholder="Enter Amount"></input>
            <select name="dropdown">
                <option value="USD">US Dollar (USD)</option>
                <option value="GDP">Great British Pound (GDP)</option>
                <option value="EUR">Euro (EUR)</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo @$output; ?>" disabled>
            <select name="odropdown">
                <option value="USD">US Dollar (USD)</option>
                <option value="GDP" selected>Great British Pound (GDP)</option>
                <option value="EUR">Euro (EUR)</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="sbmt" value="Convert!"></input>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php

$cc_input = $_GET['input'];
$cc_dropdown = $_GET['dropdown'];
$cc_odropdown = $_GET['odropdown'];

if(isset($_GET['smbt']))
{
    if($cc_dropdown == 'USD') {
        if($cc_odropdown == 'USD') {
            $output = $cc_input * 1;
            echo $output;
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'EUR') {
            $output = $cc_input * 0.897748;
            echo $output;
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'GDP') {
            $output = $cc_input * 0.753608;
            echo $output;
        }
    }
    elseif($cc_dropdown == 'EUR') {
        if($cc_odropdown == 'USD') {
            $output = $cc_input * 1.11390;
            echo $output;
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'EUR') {
            $output = $cc_input * 1;
            echo $output;
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'GDP') {
            $output = $cc_input * 0.83944;
            echo $output;
        }
    }
    elseif($cc_dropdown == 'GDP') {
        if($cc_odropdown == 'USD') {
            $output = $cc_input *   1.32695;
            echo $output;
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'EUR') {
            $output = $cc_input * 1.19127;
            echo $output;
        } elseif($cc_odropdown == 'GDP') {
            $output = $cc_input * 1;
            echo $output;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

When I Try it and Click on Convert! nothing happens why? Also there are no errors in the php built in developer server. it just says /index.php?input=1&dropdown=USD&odropdown=GDP&sbmt=Convert%21 in green.

Comment: Does it just output a blank page? Anything at all? Have you got error reporting on? `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of page to change a default setting

Comment: no it does not as I said no errors were given

Comment: also its GBP not GDP :P

Comment: no it does not as I said no errors were given

Comment: Found it.  `<input type="submit" name="sbmt"` `if(isset($_GET['smbt']))` :)

Comment: so is there a problem there?

Comment: I would hope you can see it.. but if you cant... `sbmt != smbt` => this fails your `isset()` since names don't match so the code past that is never executed hence why nothing is returned.